# MAE value for each folder in datasets

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have image datasets with subfolders labelled with age, I need to do regression using pretrained model VGG16, I have created to following code as custom matrix, it is not working. Could anyone please help me with the corrections. Thanks

```
def single_class_mae(interesting_class_id):
    def mae1(y_true, y_pred):
        class_id_true = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
        class_id_pred = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
        precision_mask = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_pred, 
        interesting_class_id), 'int32')
        class_prec_tensor = K.cast(K.equal(class_id_true, 
        class_id_pred), 'int32') * precision_mask
        K.cast(K.maximum(K.sum(precision_mask), 1), 'float32')
        a=K.mean(K.abs(precision_mask - 
         class_prec_tensor),axis=-1)  
       
        return a
    mae1.__name__ = 'mae1_1_{}'.format(interesting_class_id)
    return mae1
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by _it is not working_?

Comment: It is not working for evaluating MAE for each class in datasets.

Comment: Hi @MonikaRoopak, Could you please let us know the output of your code or error if any.  Thank You.